# Find empty keys in array of object using javascript (Es6,typescript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, object, ecmascript-6

I have an array of objects. In that array of objects I have to find which keys have empty value with index of array. Array list is given below:

```
let fruits=[
   {name:"apple",quantity:2,price:"" },
   {name:"orange",quantity:" ",price:"2"},
   {name:"banana",quantity:" ",price:""}
];
```

so here i have to find any of object key having empty value which should return key with index. i have tried using `.findIndex()` and other methods but unfortunately i can't. I am new to es6 and typescript. i need to check key with empty value in array of object.

Comment: Please include the tried code, also the expected output.

Comment: Is `quantity:" "` considered an empty value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following example

```js
let fruits = [
  { name: "apple", quantity: 2, price: "" },
  { name: "orange", quantity: "", price: "2" },
  { name: "banana", quantity: "", price: "" },
];

const output = fruits.reduce((previousValue, currentValue, currentIndex) => {
  const keys = Object.keys(currentValue).filter((key) => !currentValue[key]);

  if (keys.length) {
    previousValue[currentIndex] = keys;
  }

  return previousValue;
}, {});

console.log(output);
```

See

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

Answer (score 2):

This should do what you want. It will "map" through your array and will find for each object the keys of properties that are empty or a blank string. Then the so filtered items are "mapped" again with all the found keys being "joined" into a comma separated list (property "f") together with the "id" of the object. As a last step I filter out all those objects where the "f" property actually contains key name(s).

```js
let fruits=[
{name:"apple",quantity:2,price:"" },
   {name:"orange",quantity:" ",price:"2"},

{name:"pineapple",quantity:3,price:5},
   {name:"banana",quantity:" ",price:""}
   ];

let empty=fruits.map(f=>
  Object.keys(f).filter(k=>!(""+f[k]).trim()))
.map((f,i)=>({id:i,f:f.join(',')}))
.filter(f=>f.f)

console.log(empty)
```

In my example I added another fruit ("pineapple") with a complete set of filled properties. My snippet considers strings containing only blanks as "empty".

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're looking to get fruits that do not have a `price` value, you'll need to run a filter since your fruits is an array.

```
let emptyPriceFruits = fruits.filter((fruit) => !fruit.price)
```

Additional reading on `.filter` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Answer (score 0):

How about this one, by taking `entries` of object and then using `filter` to identify deuplicate values:

```js
var fruits=[ {name:"apple",quantity:2,price:"", pal:null }, {name:"orange",quantity:" ",price:"2"}, {name:"banana",quantity:" ",price:""}];

var emptyResult = fruits.map(k=>Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(k).filter(([k,v])=>typeof v=='string' && !v.trim())));

console.log(emptyResult);
```